# Why PhpStorm doesn't recognize methods included in a class with traits?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

To explain the essence of the problem, I sketched a small structure for an example, imagine that we want to interact with a certain service through api.

MyService folder structure:

[image]

MyService.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\MyService;

use App\Services\MyService\API\Api;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class MyService
{
    public Api $api;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->api = App::make(Api::class);
    }
}
```

Api.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\MyService\API;

use App\Services\MyService\API\Interfaces;

class Api
{
    public Interfaces\UpdateCenter $updateCenter;

    public function __construct(
        Interfaces\UpdateCenter $updateCenter
    ) {
        $this->updateCenter = $updateCenter;
    }
}
```

Interfaces\UpdateCenter.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\MyService\API\Interfaces;

interface UpdateCenter
{
    public function getApiVersion(): string;
}
```

UpdateCenter.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\MyService\API\Layers\UpdateCenter;

use App\Services\MyService\API\Layers\UpdateCenter\Methods;
use App\Services\MyService\API\Interfaces;

class UpdateCenter implements Interfaces\UpdateCenter
{
    use Methods\GetApiVersion;
}
```

GetApiVersion.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\MyService\API\Layers\UpdateCenter\Methods;

trait GetApiVersion
{
    public function getApiVersion(): string
    {
        return '1.0.0';
    }
}
```

Now here's what happens if we look at the PhpStorm hints when calling the getApiVersion() method:

```
<?php

$myService = new MyService();
$versionInfo = $myService->api->updateCenter->getApiVersion('1.0.0');
```

[image: image1]

PhpStorm can't recognize which arguments should be passed to the method, etc, but, if we remove the GetApiVersion trait and add the function directly to the UpdateCenter class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\MyService\API\Layers\UpdateCenter;

use App\Services\MyService\API\Interfaces;

class UpdateCenter implements Interfaces\UpdateCenter
{
    public function getApiVersion(): string
    {
        return '1.0.0';
    }
}
```

then phpStorm will start to recognize everything correctly:

[image]

It also begins to recognize if, during dependency injection, it is not an interface (abstraction) that is passed, but the Update Center class immediately:

**UPDATE:**
I added an archive with an example to google drive.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x6K5ocKfM_W7VVm9n9Md_LbYgm3FF6Ol/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: 1) What warning message does PhpStorm actually show? I'm referring to this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQNFd.png 2) Looks like you have done the standalone example. Can you please ZIP the whole thing and share it (so it can be tested locally without recreating it all manually).

Comment: The JetBrains support crew can be pretty helpful. You may wish to consult them.

Comment: @LazyOne i added an archive to google drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x6K5ocKfM_W7VVm9n9Md_LbYgm3FF6Ol/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @volama1699 Thanks. For me in my 2023.1.4 (not using the latest 2023.2 yet sadly) I see the same overall behavior (not the same wording, but the "unknown/incomplete" signature). Please submit a ticket at PhpStorm Issue Tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI . I've checked but could not find the exact match ticket although there were a few that should be related. Make a ticket and let PhpStorm Support to look into (they better know their own software and existing tickets). Maybe it's https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-71545 . or maybe some another ticket.